# collectionView cell Image change when scrolling - swift - programmatically

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uiimageview, uicollectionviewcell, sdwebimage

I need to load an ImageView inside `UIcollectionViewcell` using a `URL` that I pass during initialisation:

```
func configureCellWith(messageModel : MessageModel){
    
    guard let url = URL(string: messageModel.contentUrl!) else { return }
    
    if url.isURLPhoto(){
        likedImageView.sd_setImage(with: url, placeholderImage: nil)
    }
    else if url.isURLVideo(){
        getThumbnailImageFromVideoUrl(url: url) { (image) in
            self.likedImageView.image = image
    }
}
```

If url is video I need to load the image in this way using this method:

```
func getThumbnailImageFromVideoUrl(url: URL, completion: @escaping ((_ image: UIImage?)->Void)) {
    DispatchQueue.global().async {
        let asset = AVAsset(url: url)
        let avAssetImageGenerator = AVAssetImageGenerator(asset: asset)
        avAssetImageGenerator.appliesPreferredTrackTransform = true
        let thumnailTime = CMTimeMake(value: 2, timescale: 1)
        do {
            let cgThumbImage = try avAssetImageGenerator.copyCGImage(at: thumnailTime, actualTime: nil)
            let thumbNailImage = UIImage(cgImage: cgThumbImage)
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                completion(thumbNailImage)
            }
        } catch {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                completion(nil)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As visible I retrieve the initial frame of the video and I load it inside the cell, obviously since it's an asynchronous function it will take some time for loading the image, there's no problem In that.

The problem occurs when I scroll through the collection and I see that some cells display images which don't correspond to the correct ones.

Searching online I found out that I need to clear the image in `prepareForReuse` of the cell and so I did (both in case the image is loaded through `sd_setImage` and though `getThumbnailImageFromVideoUrl`  function):

```
override func prepareForReuse() {
    super.prepareForReuse()
    self.likedImageView.image = UIImage()
    self.likedImageView.image = nil
    self.likedImageView.sd_cancelCurrentImageLoad()
    
}
```

but I still get images mismatched when scrolling thought the `collection view`, what could be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue is not with images, i guess its with video thumbnail. You generate a thumbnail on background thread synchronously but while setting it back to imageView you never bothered to find if the cell is reused and the image u just created is outdated or not.

So in your cell

```
var  currentModel: MessageModel! = nil //declare a instance variable to hold model
... other code

func configureCellWith(messageModel : MessageModel){
    self.currentModel = messageModel //keep a copy of model passed to u as argument

    guard let url = URL(string: messageModel.contentUrl!) else { return }
    
    if url.isURLPhoto(){
        likedImageView.sd_setImage(with: url, placeholderImage: nil)
    }
    else if url.isURLVideo(){
        getThumbnailImageFromVideoUrl(url: url) { (image) in
            self.likedImageView.image = image
    }
}
```

Finally in `getThumbnailImageFromVideoUrl`

```
func getThumbnailImageFromVideoUrl(url: URL, completion: @escaping ((_ image: UIImage?)->Void)) {
        DispatchQueue.global().async {
            let asset = AVAsset(url: url)
            let avAssetImageGenerator = AVAssetImageGenerator(asset: asset)
            avAssetImageGenerator.appliesPreferredTrackTransform = true
            let thumnailTime = CMTimeMake(value: 2, timescale: 1)
            do {
                let cgThumbImage = try avAssetImageGenerator.copyCGImage(at: thumnailTime, actualTime: nil)
                let thumbNailImage = UIImage(cgImage: cgThumbImage)
                if url.absoluteString == currentModel.contentUrl { //check if image you generated is still valid or its no longer needed
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        completion(thumbNailImage)
                    }
                }
            } catch {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    completion(nil)
                }
            }
        }
```